# Express Session cookies not being saved in Chrome?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, express-session

I have an express session set up to use cookies which get stored in a database. This works perfectly in firefox, but it chrome it doesn't seem to ever save the cookie, so the session is never reflected by the client.

```
app.use(expressSession({ 
  secret: data[0],
  cookie: { 
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, //14 days
  },
  store: new connectMongo({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));
```

In firefox, it definitely saves a cookie as connect.sid, and saves data between page loads:
[image]

In chrome, it saves some of my browser side set cookies, such as analytics and ones I do with javascript, but connect.sid is never saved.

[image]

EDIT: so I've discovered it has to do with `secure: true`, but I don't want to disable it if I don't have to.

I thought it had to do with [xhr.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) but that didn't seem to fix it, plus the page says that it doesn't affect same-site requests, which mine always are.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your were hosting your server but after struggling with similar problem  you can use the following line, it could be that your server is hosted in places such as heroku as per this other stack overflow thread [PassportJS callback switch between http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739744/passportjs-callback-switch-between-http-and-https)

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the cookie were not being saved when deployed. If your backend server and frontend app are hosted on **different domain** i.e. **different IP.** The reason it works on **firefox** it still **shows warning** if **sameSite** attribute **value** is **not provided** and but **allow** the **cookie** to be set in browser for **cross-domain context**. whereas, in all the **chromium** based application if the **sameSite** attribute value is **not provided** in the cookie for cross-domain context, then the **cookies** are **not** being **set** or **saved** in the browser thus in turn these cookie are **not** being **sent** along **with** the **request** to server to fetch a user's data.

- Then you need to set `sameSite:'none'` which indicates whether a **cookie** is **intended** to be used in a **cross-site context**.
- Also, **Secure attribute** must be set to **true** `secure: true` when the **SameSite attribute** has been set to `'none'`. To protect user data from cross-site request forgery, policy **adopted** by **most browser** which will in turn **prevent** your **cookie** from being **saved**. **for more info** check [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#:%7E:text=Note%20There%20is%20a%20draft%20spec%20that%20requires%20that%20the%20Secure%20attribute%20be%20set%20to%20true%20when%20the%20SameSite%20attribute%20has%20been%20set%20to%20%27none%27.%20Some%20web%20browsers%20or%20other%20clients%20may%20be%20adopting%20this%20specification.)
- If **secure** is set **true**, and your **request** to the server is **sent** over **HTTP**, the cookie will not be saved in the browser. check [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value:%7E:text=Note%3A%20A%20Secure%20cookie%20is%20only%20sent%20to%20the%20server%20with%20an%20encrypted%20request%20over%20the%20HTTPS%20protocol.%20Note%20that%20insecure%20sites%20(http%3A)%20can%27t%20set%20cookies%20with%20the%20Secure%20directive%2C%20and%20therefore%20can%27t%20use%20SameSite%3DNone.)
- If you have your **node.js** behind a **proxy** and are using `secure: true`, you need to set **"trust proxy"** in express:

```
// app.set('trust proxy', 1); //either use this or set proxy:true when setting up 
app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'session secret',
        cookie: {
            sameSite: 'none',
            secure: true,  
            maxAge: 30000
        },
        proxy: true, //or use this
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: MongoStore.create({
            mongoUrl: 'database uri',
        }),
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sessionOptions = {
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie:{
        expires: Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
  };
app.use(session(sessionOptions));
```

use this before all your routes otherwise, it will not work in Chrome.